# how to store some extra information with one to ne relation with the user

Tags: python, django

I am trying to store some extra information about the user that has just logged in. Actually I have a different form that the looged in user need to fill up once the page is loaded. I want the extra information to be stored against the User that has logged in. I have assigned a one to one relationship but I am getting this error.

```
Cannot assign "'username'": "PersonalDetail.user" must be a "User" instance
```

**models**

```
class PersonalDetail(models.Model):
    user= models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age= models.IntegerField( null=True)
    phone= models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True )
    pan= models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    enrollment_no= models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    state= models.CharField(max_length=40 , null=True)
```

**views**

```
  if request.method =='POST':
         user= request.POST.get("user")
         age= request.POST.get("age") 
         phone= request.POST.get("phone")
         pan= request.POST.get("pan")
         enrollment_no= request.POST.get("enrollment_no")
         state = request.POST.get("state")
         details=PersonalDetail(user=user ,age=age,  phone= phone,  pan= pan, enrollment_no=enrollment_no, state=state )
         details.save()
         return render(request, 'consult.html')
```

I am beginner please correct my code since I am not able to store these information against the logged in userID or username. This form is recived the logged in user in side the page that he emters so this has to be stored in a different table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't take the user information from the form.
in the `view.py`

```
if request.method =='POST':
         age= request.POST.get("age") 
         phone= request.POST.get("phone")
         pan= request.POST.get("pan")
         enrollment_no= request.POST.get("enrollment_no")
         state = request.POST.get("state")
         user = request.user
         details=PersonalDetail(user=user ,age=age,  phone= phone,  pan= pan, enrollment_no=enrollment_no, state=state )
         details.save()
         return render(request, 'consult.html')
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much sir it worked perfectly......if you don't mind can you also tell me how can I print these extra info in html like the user name is printed as {{user.first_name}}.....if I want to print the age phone number etc how shal i write it {{user.personaldetail.age}}? Like this?

Comment: I think no, pass the values of personaldetail then that for that user.

Comment: @RitankarBhattacharjee if the solution solves your problem approve the answer.

Comment: Yes yes the solution solved my problem thank you @Jafoor